# Extend DHCP subnet scope of Time Capsule

Tags: wireless-networking, time-capsule

I am sitting here with a Time Capsule that I use as a DHCP server with a `10.0.1.0/24` network. I really want to extend the scope so it becomes a `/16` instead.

Is this possible on the Time Capsule or will I have to setup another DHCP server?

Answer (score 0):

> AirPort Utility provides a quick and easy way to set up your Time
>   Capsule and network. If you want to set additional options for your
>   network, such as restricting access to your network or setting
>   advanced DHCP options, choose Manual Setup from the Base Station menu
>   of AirPort Utility.

That could be helpful. 
Source: [timecapsule setup guide](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en/TimeCapsule_SetupGuide.pdf)

Comment: I have found it, but it is not letting me change subnet mask in any way shape or form :) h